# JS: name of last input element (HTML/PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, field

I better make a list in order to explain the steps that I would like to do:

1. Get the name of the last element of the html-input (has been generated via PHP)

The basic setting looks like this:

```
<input type='text'name='E_8' value= '123' />
<input type='text'name='E_9' value= '456' />
<input type='text'name='E_10' value= '789' />
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Update'/>
```

2. Pass it over to a JS function
3. Append some additional fields (use part of the name as an id for new fields

The JS-script works fine and I am able to add fields. Also the content of the fields is being processed by the PHP script and written in a db.

Short: how do I get the last value, no matter how many fields there are?

edit: I had forgotten that there is a submit button that would appear as the last element as well ... sorry for that

Comment: Do you want to know the **value** or the **name attribute** of the last text input?

Comment: You didn’t post the JS code, which is where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of approaches, but given all other answers rely on the jQuery library (which adds an unnecessary overhead), I'll focus on showing some plain JavaScript approaches (works on recents browsers above IE8+).

```
var allTextInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]'),
    lastInput = allTextInputs[allTextInputs.length - 1],
    lastInputName = lastInput.name;
```

```js
var allInputsTxt = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
var lastInput = allInputsTxt[allInputsTxt.length - 1];
var lastInputName = lastInput.name;
var lastInputValue = lastInput.value;
alert('last input name : ' + lastInputName + '; last input value : ' + lastInputValue);
```

```html
<input type='text'name='E_8' value= '123' />
<input type='text'name='E_9' value= '456' />
<input type='text'name='E_10' value= '789' />
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Update'/>
```

If what you want is the **value** and not the *`name`* attribute, do this after using the same approach as above to get the name of the last `<input type="text"/>`:

```
var lastInputValue = lastInput.value;
```

These approaches will give the value of the last `<input />` of the `type="text"` in the document at the point at which the code is run; to find the value of a last `<input />` that's dynamically added to the document, you'll need to re-run a working approach following that element's insertion.

Comment: Viewing the edit in the question with the appearance of the `submit` button at the end of the input list, only your alternative method with the `querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]')` will work.

Comment: OK ... I have pinpointed the specific part (console.log(allInputs[12]);), which prints the following to the console (<input type="text" value="789" name="E_10">) ... but how do I go on from there. What is it that I have there once I pass it over into a variable?

Comment: @DestructionOfPlanetNeptune the `allInputsTxt` is a tab containing all the `input type="text"` elements. The `lastInput` variable is the input you want. Just do what you want with it: get the name attribute? => `lastInput.name`. get the value? => ` lastInput.value`, and so on.

Comment: Works like a charm ... I used `lastInput.name` in order to get the name and then the `substring` method in order to extract what I need ... Thanks ...

Comment: @DestructionOfPlanetNeptune no problems. Don't forget to mark this as your answer. It will make David happy ;)

Comment: I have ... and with the help of `ParseInt() / Number()` -- I tried both -- I have been able to make use of the number. But, as I have just realized, I need to fix the javascript function a bit, because the settings is now a bit different, compared with the first time that I have used it. There is always something to do, isn't there? ;)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery...

```
var lastInputName = $('input[type="text"]:last').attr('name');
```

Comment: Hm ... works fine, except that the result would be the submit button. But it is my error, because I had forgotten to mention that there is a submit button. Any way to get the last but one input element?

Comment: @DestructionOfPlanetNeptune I've made the changes, see code now.

Answer (score 0):

The following jQuery code should do the trick.

```
var lastValue = $("input[type=text]:last").val();
```

Also with jQuery:

```
var $inputs = $("input[type=text]");
var lastValue = $inputs[$inputs.length - 1].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [CSS3 selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) in combination with [sizzle (jquery)](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to target last element

```
var name = $('input[name^=E_]:last')[0].name
```

Answer (score 0):

the last value in PHP or JavaScript?
in PHP the fields are normally passed as an array, so you can get the last value using

```
end($array)
```

Even better if you name your filed like this

```
<input type='text'name='E[8]' value= '123' />
<input type='text'name='E[9]' value= '456' />
<input type='text'name='E[10]' value= '789' />
```

in JS you need to get the fields into an array and get the last.... you need something like this

```
var myFields = document.forms["myform"].getElementsByTagName('input'),
var lastValue = myFields[(myFields.length-1)].value;
```

Comment: I generate the site via PHP. I will keep this in mind, but it would lead to a revamping of a good amount of code. Maybe it might make things more dicfficult maybe not. I would have think about this.

Answer (score 0):

By wrapping your code a parent element, let's says with an attribute `id="inputs"`, here is a vanilla DOM (no jQuery) solution :

```
// start by finding the last-most element
var lastInput = document.getElementById('inputs').lastElementChild;
// search backward to the last 'text' element
while (lastInput && lastInput.type !== 'text') {
    lastInput = lastInput.previousElementSibling;
}
// and get its value
var lastValue = lastInput ? lastInput.value : null;
```

The interesting part of this solution is that is create no array, so you save some JavaScript memory.
It should be ok with Firefox, Chrome and IE 9.